# What's the simplest way to check that values aren't empty in 2D array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

For example, I have an array like this:

> array(4) ( "a" => string(0) "" "b" => string(0) "" "c" => string(0) "" "d" => string(0) "" )

None of given values should be empty.

At the moment, I use this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['x']['a']) && !empty($_POST['x']['b']) && !empty($_POST['x']['c']) && !empty($_POST['x']['d']))
```

...and that sucks from readability aspect.

Note: Array is associative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
count(array_filter($_POST['x'])) === 4
```

Some Explanation: [Empty() is the Opposite of a Boolean Variable](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/php-empty-is-the-opposite-of-a-boolean-variable/), `array_filter` removes all elements that equal false (which is `!empty()`) and this count must match the expectation of 4 elements then.

If the number of elements is defined by the total of elements submitted (empty or not), use count() instead the magic number:

```
if (count(array_filter($_POST['x'])) === count($_POST['x']))
{
    echo 'No empty elements in $_POST["x"]!';
}
```

Comment: I don't need to check count of them. I need to check emptiness.

Comment: @daGrevis array_filter (without a callback passed) returns an array of values from `$_POST['a']` that are != false. hakre is then just getting a count of that result array. If the count of that result array matches the count of the original array, then there are no empty values.

Comment: @daGrevis: It checks for the count of non-empty elements.

Comment: Hmm... on Kohana: `Fatal error: Class declarations may not be nested in ...\system\classes\date.php on line 3`.

Comment: @hakre Somehow. Without new code in `if` statement all works. Now I'm trying to figure out is it PHP, Kohana or my error.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: (in response to comments)**

You can encapsulate the "uncool" logic in a function and call it with a one-liner:

```
if ( check_for_empty_values( $_POST ) ) { // Do something }
```

The encapsulated checking logic:

```
function check_for_empty_values( $data ) {
    $valid = true;
    foreach ( $data as $element ) {
        if ( is_array( $element) ) {
            foreach ( $element as $subelement ) {
                if ( empty( $subelement ) ) {
                    $valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

Comment: This will only check one element at a time.

Comment: This is basic way to do it. I'm looking for something more cool! =P I will accept this answer if none will came up with anything better...

Comment: @deGrevis: See my updated answer for a way to address both form and substance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the array_reduce function ?

```
function all_empty($v,$w){
   $v .= $w;
   return $v;
}
if(array_reduce($_POST['x'],'all_empty','')==''){
```

I haven't tested, but you can give this a try

Comment: You can even make the function recursive: `if(is_array($w)) $w = array_reduce($w,'all_empty',$v);`

Answer (score -2):

```
for($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if( !empty($value) ) {
      // Do stuff.    

    }
}
```